# Can I use an existing EFI partition as /boot?

Tags: systemd, boot, grub2, backup, uefi

So I'm planning to switch full-time to Pop_OS! and while backing up (which is another can of worms I'll be explaining later), I realized "Wait, do I have to create a new partition for boot? Or can I use an existing one?" I didn't really know what the answer to that was so I decided, before switching to Pop_OS!, I'm gonna ask here.

**Can I use an existing EFI partition as /boot?**

Now, I'm gonna cover the second can of worms I was talking about. So while I was backing everything up, this anxiety crept in like "Is everything backed up? Can I be sure that the copy process didn't fail? HAVE I BACKED UP EVERYTHING I WANT?!" and this anxiety is keeping me from fully committing to linux. So the 2nd question of the thread is:

**How can I overcome the anxiety of whether or not I've backed up everything?**

Comment: I only have a single EFI partition on my hard drive. It's the same that Windows uses for its boot manager. (I'm planning to fully switch to Pop_OS!, no dualboot)

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Well uh.... what's **[this](https://imgur.com/a/4Rl2NZ2)** then?

Comment: So I can use it for /boot?

Comment: Normally /boot is inside / as a folder for most desktop systems. You can create separate /boot partition for for Linux it must be Linux formatted, not FAT32. And often /boot partition only for some server type installs.  But POP_OS can use SystemD boot which does put some additional files into the ESP. But you typically need a larger ESP. SystemD boot
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd-boot#Installing_the_EFI_boot_manager

Comment: A lot of nitpicking in the comments here. If a disk contains several **GPT** partitions, that doesn't make them **EFI** partitions, especially if the partitions are formatted using a filesystem that the EFI firmware knows nothing about. @oldfred who says the Linux  boot partition can't be on the ESP? I have been using this for years now with Arch Linux. Some other distros may frown upon doing this, but that doesn't make it impossible in general. And while we're nitpicking: systemd is not spelled wit a capital D.

Comment: Technically, you can.  Practically, you don't want to because: 1. The EFI system partition is typically very small, usually a few tens or hundreds of megabytes to hold the EFI boot loader(s). Using it as `/boot` as well will require enough additional space for a few kernels (5-15 MB each) and initrds (30-100 MB each) and grub's own files (~ 12 MB). If you really must do this, give it at least 2 or 5 GB. 2. The EFI partition needs to be formatted as FAT which means that it doesn't support unix ownership, groups, or permissions. or ACLs either (but who even uses ACLs on /boot? probably nobody)

Comment: As for your backup anxiety, either backup everything again or use a backup method that allows you to verify that what was backed up matches the original files (most backup utils have a verify option), or both.   Get one or more USB sticks or USB external drives and make multiple backups, the more the better :)

Comment: @cas Thanks for addressing the "backup anxiety", I decided to use Windows 10's "Create a system image" feature which allows you to backup the *whole* drive. So my anxiety has calmed down a little bit.

Still, thanks for addressing it :)

Comment: @cas Also, from what I get from your comment regarding the EFI partition, it seems then like using the EFI partition as `/boot` is bad practice, and Pop!_OS installs SystemD/Grub/whatever into the EFI partition mounted at `/boot/EFI` by itself, correct?

Comment: Yes, it's possible but bad practice.   I don't know for sure what popos does, but `/boot/EFI` is probably where it mounts the EFI System Partition (which is where the UEFI BIOS looks for EFI boot loaders)  - it's a fairly common mount-point for that.      `/boot` (which can be a partition or a sub-directory of /) is where kernel images and initrds are stored.  `/boot/grub` (which, again, can be a partition or a subdirectory of `/boot`) is where grub stores its own files (config files and binaries needed for various boot options).

Comment: BTW, it's also not uncommon to store ISO images (which can be booted with [memdisk](https://wiki.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=MEMDISK) or similar) in `/boot` (or sub-directories of /boot - I have mine in `/boot/ISO/`) too.  e.g. an ISO image file of the [gparted](https://gparted.org/) or [clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/) CD which can be booted by selecting it from the grub menu.